# If there is a sequence $(a_n) \subseteq U \setminus \{a\} $ such that $(a_n) \rightarrow a $ and $f(a_n) = f(a)$ for all $n$. then $f'(a) = 0$

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that a is an interior point of $U$ and that $f: U \rightarrow R$ is differentiable at $a$. If there is a sequence $(a_n) \subseteq U \setminus \{a\} $ such that $(a_n) \rightarrow a $ and $f(a_n) = f(a)$ for all $n$. then $f'(a) = 0$

What Im thinking was since $f$ is differentiable at $a$, $$\lim_{a_n\to a} |\frac{f(a_n) - f(a)}{a_n-a} - f'(a)| <\epsilon $$. Since $f(a_n) = f(a) $, $lim = |f'(a) | < \epsilon $. Therefore $f'(a) = 0$

Is this proof wrong or i missed something?

Comment: Use directly the definition of derivative and calculate it to be zero, you won't need epsilon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is correct, but you appear to mixing two different approaches in your statement of it. One approach is this: by definition of the derivative,
$$\lim_{x \to a}\frac {f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} = f'(a)$$
Since $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$, we have therefore $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(a_n) - f(a)}{a_n - a} = f'(a)$$ But as you note, the fraction on the LHS is always $0$, so its limit is $0$.

The issue with that approach is that the change of limits from the continuous limit to the sequential limit may seem questionable to those who are not well-versed in them. So the other approach is to justify the change by falling back to the definitions of the limits:

By definition of the limit, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there is a $\delta > 0$ such that $\left|\frac{f(x) - f(a)}{x - a} - f'(a)\right| < \epsilon$ when $\left|x - a\right| < \delta$. But since $a_n \to a$ as $n \to \infty$, there is an $N$ such that if $n > N$, then $\left|a_n - a\right| < \delta$. And hence, $\left|\frac{f(a_n) - f(a)}{a_n - a} - f'(a)\right| < \epsilon$. But since $f(a_n) = f(a)$, this is just $\left|f'(a)\right| < \epsilon$. Since this holds for all $\epsilon > 0$, we must have $f'(a) = 0$.